# Tumblr page images duplicating on homepage only

Tags: tumblr

Have never used Tumblr but have been asked to troubleshoot an issue we are having, so please forgive me if I don't get the Tumblr terminology correct.

The homepage of the Tumblr account is duplicating all images. When you click into a post there is only one image on the post page, its just on the homepage that two of each image is appearing.

I have attached some front page code which I hope will help identify the issue and if someone can spot the problem I would appreciate it if you could tell me the exact file I need to edit and where as I have never used Tumblr before. Many thanks.

```
   <!doctype html>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                {block:IfNotEnableImgOnlyLogo}
                <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="{image:Logo}" alt="{Title}"><span>{Title}</span></a>
                {/block:IfNotEnableImgOnlyLogo}
                {block:IfEnableImgOnlyLogo}
                <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="{image:Logo}" alt="{Title}"></a>
                {/block:IfEnableImgOnlyLogo}
                <nav>
                    {block:HasPages}
                    <ul class="pages">
                        {block:Pages}
                        <li><a href="{URL}" title="{Label}">{Label}</a></li>
                        {/block:Pages}
                    </ul>
                    {/block:HasPages}
<ul class="filter" data-dropdown="dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">{text:Filter Menu Name}:</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {block:Pages}
                                <li class="pages-in-nav"><a href="{URL}" title="{Label}">{Label} Page</a></li>
                                {/block:Pages}
                                {block:SubmissionsEnabled}
                                <li><a href="/submit">{block:IfSubmitText}{text:Submit Text}{/block:IfSubmitText}</a></li>
                                {/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
                                <li><a href="/">All</a></li>
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag1}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 1}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 1}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag1}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag2}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 2}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 2}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag2}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag3}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 3}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 3}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag3}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag4}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 4}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 4}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag4}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag5}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 5}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 5}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag5}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag6}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 6}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 6}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag6}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag7}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 7}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 7}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag7}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag8}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 8}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 8}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag8}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag9}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 9}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 9}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag9}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag10}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 10}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 10}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag10}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag11}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 11}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 11}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag11}
                                {block:IfFilterMenuTag12}
                                <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 12}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 12}</a></li>
                                {/block:IfFilterMenuTag12}
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="post-wrapper">
            <section class="{block:IndexPage}page-index{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}page-permalink{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:SearchPage}page-search{/block:SearchPage}" id="posts">
                {block:TagPage}
                <div class="pagination prev-page tag-results">
                    <p class="details"><span class="icon">X</span>Displaying posts tagged: <strong>{Tag}</strong></p>
                </div>
                {/block:TagPage}
                {block:Pagination}
                {block:PreviousPage}
                <div class="pagination prev-page">
                    <a href="{PreviousPage}" class="load">Load <strong>Prev</strong> Page</a>
                </div>
                {/block:PreviousPage}
                {/block:Pagination}
                {block:Posts}
                <article class="post {PostType} {TagsAsClasses} {block:Photoset}photoset{/block:Photoset}" id="{PostID}">
                    {block:Text}
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        {block:Title}
                        <a href="{Permalink}" title="{Title}" class="title"><h1>{Title}</h1></a>
                        {/block:Title}
                    </div>
                    <div class="lines">
                        {Body}
                    </div>
                    {/block:Text}
                    {block:Photo}
                    {block:IndexPage}
                    <a href="{Permalink}" title="{PhotoAlt}" class="view" rel="{PostID}" data-click-through="" data-replaced="False">
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" data-250="{PhotoURL-250}" data-400="{PhotoURL-400}" data-500="{PhotoURL-500}" data-1280="{block:HighRes}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:HighRes}" data-replaced="False">
                    </a>
                    {/block:IndexPage}

                    <a href="{PhotoURL-250}" title="{PhotoAlt}" class="view" rel="{PostID}" data-click-through="{LinkURL}" data-replaced="False">
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" data-250="{PhotoURL-250}" data-400="{PhotoURL-400}" data-500="{PhotoURL-500}" data-1280="{block:HighRes}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:HighRes}" data-replaced="False">
                    </a>
                    {block:Caption}
                    <div class="lines">
                        {Caption}
                    </div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                {/block:PermalinkPage}
                    {/block:Photo}
                    {block:Photoset}
                    <ul class="photoset-grid"id="photoset-grid{PostID}" data-grid-array="{PlaintextPhotosetLayout}">
                        {block:Photos}

                        <li>
                            {block:IndexPage}
                            <a href="{Permalink}" title="{display:Caption}{PlaintextCaption}{/display:Caption}" class="view" rel="{PostID}" data-click-through="" data-replaced="False">
                                <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" data-250="{PhotoURL-250}" data-400="{PhotoURL-400}" data-500="{PhotoURL-500}" data-1280="{block:HighRes}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:HighRes}" data-replaced="False">
                            </a>
                            {/block:IndexPage}

                            <a href="{PhotoURL-250}" title="{display:Caption}{PlaintextCaption}{/display:Caption}" class="view" rel="{PostID}" data-click-through="{LinkURL}" data-replaced="False">
                                <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" data-250="{PhotoURL-250}" data-400="{PhotoURL-400}" data-500="{PhotoURL-500}" data-1280="{block:HighRes}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:HighRes}" data-replaced="False">
                            </a>

                        </li>
                        {/block:Photos}

                    </ul>

                    {block:Caption}
                    <div class="lines">
                        {Caption}
                    </div>

                    {/block:Caption}

                    {/block:Photoset}

                    {block:Quote}
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <blockquote>
                            {Quote}
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lines">
                        {block:Source}
                        {Source}
                        {/block:Source}
                    </div>
                    {/block:Quote}
                    {block:Link}
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <a href="{URL}" target="_blank">{Name}</a>
                    </div>
                    {block:Description}
                    <div class="lines">
                        {Description}
                    </div>
                    {/block:PermalinkPage}
                    {/block:Description}
                    {/block:Link}
                    {block:Chat}
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <ul>
                            {block:Lines}
                            <li class="{Alt} user_{UserNumber}">
                                {block:Label}<b>{Label}</b>{/block:Label}
                                {Line}
                            </li>
                            {/block:Lines}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {block:Title}
                    <div class="lines">
                        <p>{Title}</p>
                    </div>
                    {/block:Title}
                    {/block:Chat}
                    {block:Video}
                    <div class="video-wrapper">
                        {Video-500}
                    </div>
                    {block:PermalinkPage}
                    {block:Caption}
                    <div class="lines">
                        {Caption}
                    </div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                    {/block:PermalinkPage}
                    {/block:Video}
                    {block:Audio}
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        {block:AlbumArt}
                        <img src="{AlbumArtURL}" alt="">
                        {/block:AlbumArt}
                        <ul class="player">
                            {block:TrackName}<li><span>Title:</span> {TrackName}</li>{/block:TrackName}
                            {block:Artist}<li><span>Artist:</span> {Artist}</li>{/block:Artist}
                            <li class="audio">{AudioPlayerWhite}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {block:PermalinkPage}
                    <div class="lines">
                        {block:Caption}
                        {Caption}
                        {/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                    {/block:PermalinkPage}
                    {/block:Audio}
                    {block:IndexPage}
                    {block:Date}
                    <ul class="footer">
                        <li class="time">
                            {block:IfNotEnableExactPostDate}
                            <span class="stamp">{TimeAgo}</span>
                            {/block:IfNotEnableExactPostDate}
                            {block:IfEnableExactPostDate}
                            <span class="stamp">{DayOfMonth}{DayOfMonthSuffix} {Month}, {Year}</span>
                            {/block:IfEnableExactPostDate}
                        </li>
                        {block:IfDisqusShortname}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{Permalink}#disqus" title="View Comments" class="disqus">
                                <span class="icon">f</span>
                                <span class="details">0</span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread" title="{lang:View comments for this post}" class="dsq-comment-count">0</a>
                        </li>
                        {/block:IfDisqusShortname}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{Permalink}#notes" title="View Notes" class="notes">
                                <span class="icon">N</span>
                                <span class="details">{block:NoteCount}{NoteCount}{/block:NoteCount}</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{Permalink}" title="View Post" class="permalink">
                                <span class="icon">?</span>
                                <span class="details">VIEW</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    {/block:Date}
                    {/block:IndexPage}
                </article>
                {/block:Posts}
                {block:Permalink}
                {block:Posts}
                {block:Date}
                <section id="post-details">
                    <h4>Post Details</h4>
                    <ul class="details">
                        <li><span class="date"><span class="icon">^</span>{DayOfMonth}{DayOfMonthSuffix} {Month}, {Year}</span></li>
                        {block:IfDisqusShortname}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{Permalink}#disqus" title="View Comments" class="disqus">
                                <span class="icon">f</span>
                                <span class="details">0</span> Comments
                            </a>
                            <a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread" title="{lang:View comments for this post}" class="dsq-comment-count">0</a>
                        </li>
                        {/block:IfDisqusShortname}
                        {block:NoteCount}<li><a href="#notes" title="Post Notes" class="notes" title="View Post Notes"><span class="icon">N</span>{NoteCount} Notes</a></li>{/block:NoteCount}
                        <li><a href="{ShortURL}" title="Post Short URL" class="short-url"><span class="icon">e</span>{ShortURL}</a></li>
                        {block:ContentSource}
                        <li><a href="{SourceURL}" target="_blank" class="source-url" title="Post Original Source"><span class="icon">c</span>{SourceTitle}</a></li>
                        {/block:ContentSource}
                    </ul>
                    {block:HasTags}
                    <ul class="tags">
                        {block:Tags}
                        <li><a href="{TagURL}" class="tag"><span class="icon">_</span>{Tag}</a></li>
                        {/block:Tags}
                    </ul>
                    {/block:HasTags}
                    <h4 id="share-title">Post Share</h4>
                    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style " addthis:title="{Title}" addthis:url="{Permalink}">
                        <a class="addthis_button_tumblr"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:count="false" style="display: block; margin-top: -2px; height:16px"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        <a class="addthis_button_pinterest" style="margin-top:10px"></a>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>
                </section>
                {block:PermalinkPagination}
                {block:IfEnablePermalinkNavigation}
                <ul class="post-nav">
                    <li id="prev-post">{block:PreviousPost}<a href="{PreviousPost}">Prev Post</a>{/block:PreviousPost}&nbsp;</li>
                    <li id="next-post">{block:NextPost}<a href="{NextPost}">Next Post</a>{/block:NextPost}</li>
                </ul>
                {/block:IfEnablePermalinkNavigation}
                {/block:PermalinkPagination}
                {block:IfDisqusShortname}
                <section id="disqus_thread">
                    <script src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/embed.js"></script>
                    <noscript><a href="http://{text:Disqus Shortname}.disqus.com/?url=ref">{lang:View the discussion thread}</a></noscript>
                </section>
                {/block:IfDisqusShortname}
                {block:IfEnablePostNotes}
                {block:PostNotes}
                {PostNotes}
                {/block:PostNotes}
                {/block:IfEnablePostNotes}
                {/block:Date}
                {/block:Posts}
                {/block:Permalink}
                {block:Pagination}
                {block:NextPage}
                <div class="pagination next-page">
                    <p class="details"><span class="icon">g</span>Posts: <strong><span class="start">?</span> - <span class="end">?</span></strong></p>
                    <a href="{NextPage}" class="load">Load <strong>Next</strong> Page</a>
                </div>
                {/block:NextPage}
                {/block:Pagination}
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                {block:HasPages}
                <ul id="site-links">
                    <li><h4>{Title} Pages</h4></li>
                    {block:Pages}
                    <li><a href="{URL}" title="{Label}">{Label}</a></li>
                    {/block:Pages}
                </ul>
                {/block:HasPages}
                <ul class="site-tags">
                    <li><h4>Browse Tags</h4></li>
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag1}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 1}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 1}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag1}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag2}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 2}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 2}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag2}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag3}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 3}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 3}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag3}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag4}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 4}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 4}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag4}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag5}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 5}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 5}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag5}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag6}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 6}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 6}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag6}
                </ul>
                <ul class="site-tags">
                    <li><h4>&nbsp;</h4></li>
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag7}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 7}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 7}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag7}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag8}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 8}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 8}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag8}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag9}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 9}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 9}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag9}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag10}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 10}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 10}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag10}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag11}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 11}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 11}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag11}
                    {block:IfFilterMenuTag12}
                    <li><a href="/tagged/{text:Filter Menu Tag 12}{block:IfNavChrono}/chrono{/block:IfNavChrono}">{text:Filter Menu Tag 12}</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFilterMenuTag12}
                </ul>
                <ul id="social-links">
                    <li><h4>Social Links</h4></li>
                    {block:IfEmailAddress}
                    <li><a href="mailto:{text:Email Address}" title="Email Me" class="email" target="_blank"><span class="icon">@</span>Email Me</a></li>
                    {/block:IfEmailAddress}
                    <li><a href="{RSS}" title="View my RSS Feed" class="rss"><span class="icon" target="_blank">B</span>RSS Feed</a></li>
                    {block:IfFacebookProfile}
                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/{text:Facebook Profile}" title="View my Facebook Profile" class="facebook" target="_blank"><span class="icon">E</span>Facebook</a></li>
                    {/block:IfFacebookProfile}
                    {block:IfTwitterProfile}
                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/{text:Twitter Profile}" title="View my Twitter Profile" class="twitter" target="_blank"><span class="icon">F</span>Twitter</a></li>
                    {/block:IfTwitterProfile}
                    {block:IfGoogleProfile}
                    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/{text:Google Profile}" title="View my Google Plus Profile" class="gplus" target="_blank"><span class="icon">D</span>Google Plus</a></li>
                    {/block:IfGoogleProfile}
                    {block:IfYouTubeProfile}
                    <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/{text:YouTube Profile}" title="View my YouTube Profile" class="youtube" target="_blank"><span class="icon">H</span>YouTube</a></li>
                    {/block:IfYouTubeProfile}
                </ul>
                {block:IfTwitterProfile}
                <div id="recent-twitter">
                    <h4>Latest Tweets</h4>
                    <ul id="tweets">
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {/block:IfTwitterProfile}
            </div>
            <div class="container" id="credits">
                <div id="tumblr-link">
                    <a href="http://www.tumblr.com" title="Powered By Tumblr" target="_blank">Powered By Tumblr</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
    <script>
    var disqusUsername = '{text:Disqus Shortname}';
    var postsPerPage   = '{text:Posts Per Page}';
    var noMorePostsMessage = '{text:No More Posts Message}';
    var removeLoadNextPageButton;
    {block:IfEnableRemoveNextPageButtonOnComplete}
    var removeLoadNextPageButton = true;
    {/block:IfEnableRemoveNextPageButtonOnComplete}
    </script>
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/g8b5dgd/t4kmcaq6e/mikedidthis-mason-general-1-5-min.js"></script>
    {block:IndexPage}
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/g8b5dgd/iqPmcaq5y/mikedidthis-mason-index-1-5-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/g8b5dgd/F2Gmcaq6q/mikedidthis-mason-index-helpers-1-5-min.js"></script>
    {/block:IndexPage}
    {block:Permalink}
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/g8b5dgd/RVxmcaq71/mikedidthis-mason-permalink-1-5-min.js"></script>
    {/block:Permalink}
    {block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID}
    <script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{text:Google Analytics ID}']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    </script>
    {/block:IfGoogleAnalyticsID}
    {block:IfTwitterProfile}
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
        $.getScript('http://static.tumblr.com/g8b5dgd/Jzdm1nbnz/jquery.tweet-min.js',function(){
            $("#tweets").tweet({
                username: "{text:Twitter Profile}",
                join_text: "auto",
                count: 2,
                auto_join_text_default: "we said,",
                auto_join_text_ed: "we",
                auto_join_text_ing: "we were",
                auto_join_text_reply: "we replied to",
                auto_join_text_url: "we were checking out",
                loading_text: "Getting latest tweet..."
            }).bind('loaded', function () {
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    {/block:IfTwitterProfile}
    {block:IfDisqusShortname}
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $.fn.disquscommentCount = function() {
            var container = $(this);
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            var query = '?';
            for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                if(links[i].href.indexOf('#disqus_thread') >= 0) {
                    query += 'url' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href) + '&';
                }
            }
            container.append('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/' + disqusUsername + '/get_num_replies.js' + query + '"></' + 'script>');
        };
        $('body').disquscommentCount();
    });
    </script>
    {/block:IfDisqusShortname}
    {block:IfEnableLoadNextPageOnScroll}
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            $('.next-page').find('.load:in-viewport').last().click().unbind('click').removeClass('load');
        });
    });
    </script>
    {/block:IfEnableLoadNextPageOnScroll}
    {block:IfEnableThemeVersionCheck}
    <script>
    $(function () {
        var url = window.location.href;
        if (url.search("customize") > 0) {
            $.getScript('http://static.tumblr.com/g8b5dgd/Wssm47lrc/mikedidthis-mason-notify-min.js');
        } else {
            if (top.location != self.location) top.location = self.location;
        }
    });
    </script>
    {/block:IfEnableThemeVersionCheck}
    </html>
```

Comment: Sadly the above code is little help. You will need to provide the template code, before it is rendered (which is the code above) before anyone can help.

Comment: Hi I added the code above, I had to leave out a load of the page code that seemed to me the CSS because its exceeded that character limit. Does the above help? Thanks

Comment: Small world, as this is my Mason Theme! It seems your missing an opening `{block:PermalinkPage}` in the `post` loop. I will try and post the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it seems your missing the `{block:PermalinkPage}` in the `{block:Photo}` loop. It should be:

```html
{block:Photo}
{block:IndexPage}
<a href="{Permalink}" title="{PhotoAlt}" class="view" rel="{PostID}" data-click-through="" data-replaced="False">
    <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" data-250="{PhotoURL-250}" data-400="{PhotoURL-400}" data-500="{PhotoURL-500}" data-1280="{block:HighRes}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:HighRes}" data-replaced="False">
</a>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
<a href="{PhotoURL-250}" title="{PhotoAlt}" class="view" rel="{PostID}" data-click-through="{LinkURL}" data-replaced="False">
    <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" data-250="{PhotoURL-250}" data-400="{PhotoURL-400}" data-500="{PhotoURL-500}" data-1280="{block:HighRes}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:HighRes}" data-replaced="False">
</a>
{block:Caption}
<div class="lines">
{Caption}
</div>
{/block:Caption}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photo}
```

That should display one image on the indexpage, one image on the permalink page. I would suggest reverting to the original HTML if your still having issues.

Comment: Awesome Mike, that worked a treat, thanks so much. Great theme btw :)